# wicket : to call javascript function from java class using target

Tags: javascript, wicket

What I have to do is to pass values fron wickets java code to javascript function using target.
For which I have use method to call javascript function from wickets java class using target.

My java code is:

```
target.addJavascript("show();");
```

Html code.
Scipt function

But it not calling javascript function - what shall i do?

Comment: First, you can check in the Wicket-Ajax-Debug window what's happening. If you still don't find the problem, don't hesitate to provide more details here.

Comment: [`addJavascript()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html#addJavascript%28java.lang.String%29) has been deprecated. Have you tried using [`appendJavascript()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html#appendJavascript%28java.lang.String%29) instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to call some JS in a update event, you have to implements a boolean method called: "wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications()"

For example:

```
new DropDownChoice("drop"){

  @Override
        protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
            return true;
        }

  @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
         target.appendJavaScript("put your JavaScript here");
   }

}
```